Validación entrada calculadora con for/if-else
me puse un rato y no encuentro solución al problema esperado/inesperado XD
el reto es usar la calculadora por ahora solo con for/if-else
System.out.println("Selecciona la operación a realizar: \n1. Suma \n2. Resta \n3. Multplicación \n4. División");
    Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
    int operacion = leer.nextInt();
    leer.nextLine();
    String nombreOperacion="";
    String otraOperacion = "";


        if(operacion == 1){
            nombreOperacion = "Suma";
        }else if(operacion == 2 ){
            nombreOperacion ="Resta";
        }else if(operacion == 3){
            nombreOperacion ="Multiplicación";
        }else if(operacion == 4){
            nombreOperacion ="División";
        }

        if (operacion>=1 && operacion<=4){
            System.out.println("Usted a seleccionado "+nombreOperacion);      
        }else{
            System.out.println("Opción no válida. \nFavor ingresar las opciones indicadas (1-4)");
        }

quiero que se valide el ingreso de la primera parte, se solicita un int, pero si usuario ingresa algo distinto deseo que lo tome y muestra que no se admite y se cierre el programa (ahora se cierra por error), ya los numeros estan cubiertos, pero esa validación no me deja tranquillo jajaja
traté
hasNextInt
Try-catch
boolean
pero se presenta el cierre por error

Una forma de hacer esto es dejar que el usuario introduzca lo que sea en un String y luego ya verificaremos si lo que ha introducido nos vale o no, pero todo desde un entorno controlado para que el programa no se cierre abruptamente.
Por lo que lo primero que haremos será leer la entrada del usuario con nextLine, de esa forma guardamos lo que haya escrito en un String (en lugar de en un Integer como cuando lo haces con nextInt).
Una vez que tenemos la entrada en un String, podemos usar el método Integer.parseInt() para verificar que lo que se ha introducido es un número entero.
Ese método lo que hace es convertir un String a Integer, pero lanza una excepción si lo que se introduce no es un número entero (por ejemplo si metes letras o símbolos como el punto, el $, etc.)
Por lo que solo necesitas capturar esa excepción y en el bloque de tratamiento de excepciones es donde metes tu lógica para informar que esa entrada no se admite. Sería algo así:
Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
String entrada = leer.nextLine();
try {
    Integer operacion = Integer.parseInt(entrada);
    // RESTO DE TU CÓDIGO
} catch(NumberFormatException ex) {
    System.err.println("No se admiten valores no numéricos");
}

Más info:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html


Vas bien encaminado, pero faltan algunas cositas, por ejemplo, los bucles, si el usuario no ingresa un valor válido, la operación de solicitarselo, debe repetirse.
int operacion = 0;

void ini() {
   Scanner leer = new Scanner( System.in );
   System.out.println( "Selecciona la operación a realizar: \n1. Suma \n2. "
           + "Resta \n3. Multplicación \n4. División" );

     // normalmente usaría un "while", pero como las condiciones son solo "for/if-else"...
     // inicializamos "operacion" en "0", para que entre en el bucle
   for( ; operacion < 1 || operacion > 4; ) {

        // ahora le asignamos el valor introducido por el usuario
        // luego si el valor no está dentro de los parámetros, enviamos el mensaje
        // la condición del "for", hará que el código se repita
      operacion = leer.nextInt();
      if( operacion < 1 || operacion > 4 ) {
         System.out.println( "Opción no válida. \nFavor ingresar las opciones indicadas (1-4)" );
      }
   }
   String nombreOperacion = "";
   if( operacion == 1 ) {
      nombreOperacion = "Suma";
   }
   else if( operacion == 2 ) {
      nombreOperacion = "Resta";
   }
   else if( operacion == 3 ) {
      nombreOperacion = "Multiplicación";
   }
   else if( operacion == 4 ) {
      nombreOperacion = "División";
   }
   System.out.println( "Usted a seleccionado " + nombreOperacion );
   leer.nextLine();
   String valueA;
   String valueB;
   int numeroEnteroA;
   int numeroEnteroB;
   double numeroDecimalA;
   double numeroDecimalB;
   boolean numerosInvalidos = true;
   String resultado = "";
   for( ; numerosInvalidos; ) {
      System.out.println( "Ingrese el primer valor" );
      valueA = leer.nextLine();
      System.out.println( "Ingrese el segundo valor" );
      valueB = leer.nextLine();

        // una vez obtenidos los valores de los supuestos números, corroboramos
        // que sean números válidos 
        // primero vemos si contiene un ".", y de ser así, intentamos parsearlo a "double",
        // si no arroja un error, llamamos mediante polimorfismo al método adecuado 
        // para obtener el resultado de la operación
      if( valueA.contains( "." ) || valueB.contains( "." ) ) {
        try {
           numeroDecimalA = Double.parseDouble( valueA );
           numeroDecimalB = Double.parseDouble( valueB );
           numerosInvalidos = false;
           resultado = operar( numeroDecimalA, numeroDecimalB );
        }
        catch( Exception e ) {
           System.out.println( "Por favor ingrese dos números válidos" );
        }
     }

       // si no contenia "." intentamos lo propio con enteros
     else {
        try {
           numeroEnteroA = Integer.parseInt( valueA );
           numeroEnteroB = Integer.parseInt( valueB );
           numerosInvalidos = false;
           resultado = operar( numeroEnteroA, numeroEnteroB );
        }
        catch( Exception e ) {
           System.out.println( "Por favor ingrese dos números válidos" );
        }
     }
  }
  System.out.println( resultado );
  leer.close();
}

String operar( int numeroA, int numeroB ) {
   if( operacion == 1 ) {
      return "" + ( numeroA + numeroB );
   }
   else if( operacion == 2 ) {
      return "" + ( numeroA - numeroB );
   }
   else if( operacion == 3 ) {
      return "" + ( numeroA * numeroB );
   }
   else {
      return "" + ( numeroA / numeroB );
   }
}

String operar( double numeroA, double numeroB ) {
   if( operacion == 1 ) {
      return "" + ( numeroA + numeroB );
   }
   else if( operacion == 2 ) {
      return "" + ( numeroA - numeroB );
   }
   else if( operacion == 3 ) {
      return "" + ( numeroA * numeroB );
   }
   else {
      return "" + ( numeroA / numeroB );
   }
}

Tranquilamente se puede obviar la distinción entre enteros y decimales, depende de lo que necesites, solo lo puse para ilustrar las distintas posibilidades.
PD: por si no lo tienes claro, el polimorfismo, es una cualidad de la POO, por la cual se llama al método adecuado, basandose en el tipo y la cantidad de los argumentos pasados.

Hola bro si, en realidad el problema que tenia era la validación inicial pues en cuenta operaciones creo que va bien... se que me puse un reto de usar solo for/if-else quizas sea algo trillado XD pero me ayudó full con esas
dejo mi repo para que lo cheques y me digas que puede mejorar... como tiene for/if-else XD por cuestión de linea solo dejé en ingreso 1 y el cambio de operación y ahí termina...

Te falto el "repo"!!!!.

https://github.com/SAFCCFAS/estudio-java

Funciona de maravilla!!!!!... ahora bien, se puede hacer más conciso, y más limpio, por ejemplo, en mi humilde opinión, cada clase en su archivo, si un metodo tiene más de 10-15 lineas, lo divido, y sobre todo, no repito código, si mirás dentro de CalculadoraI, tenés un bloque if-else if que empieza así: if(operaciones1==1){
System.out.println("ingrese primer número:");, después todo se repite, salvo por el tipo de operación, tenes que sacar el pedido de valores aun método separado, y llamarlo, luego solo resta hacer la operación, eso mismo se puede hacer en

varios lugares, por otro lado, te has olvidado de colocar los bucles, si ingreso un "6" en el inicio, me indica que el valor es incorrecto... y el programa termina. PD: podrías hacer una clase Mensaje.

bueno hasta el momento pienso hacer la simplificación a medida que voy avanzado, por ahora ando programando en dúo de ciclo y bucle, ya terminé por el momento la combinación de for/if-else... ahora estoy en una de if-switch... bueno en resumidas cuentas es hacer todas las posibles combinaciones, ir pasando los métodos que están siendo las calculadoras pasarlas a clases, y las funciones pasarlas a métodos para ir simplificando los códigos ya que al final compartirán operaciones, luego separar las clases en su respectivo archivos...
ah si claro siempre voy probando a ver que otros problemas veo

creo que si miras el repo verás que va cambiando el código poco a poco, ahora trataŕe a aprender usar try-catch pues en for/if-else usé matches
